# Labeling data for neural net training

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, cudnn

Does anyone know of or have a good tool for labeling image data to be used in training a DNN?

Specifically labeling 2 points in an image, like upperLeftCorner and lowerRightCorner, which then calculates a bouding box around the specified object. That's just an example but I would like to be able to follow the MSCoco data format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might try LabelMe, http://labelme.csail.mit.edu/Release3.0/

It's usually for outlines for segmentation, but I'm pretty sure it works fine for bounding boxes too.

Comment: Great tool thanks for sharing! Downside is your data becomes public unless you deal with standing the source up on your own server..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue finding a tool that did bouding boxes for labeling image data, so I started this new project called LabelD (https://github.com/sweppner/labeld) that uses NodeJS and focuses on bouding boxes for annotation. It's still very much in alpha, but it's pretty easy to use and functional for labeling images!

Let me know if you have any questions!